# Catch JSON object from string which contains other text

Tags: php, json

I have an issue with the API that I am using, in the response there is simple text and a json object, here is what kind of response I can have :

```
--uuid:ea9ca368-2f73-4669-aa94-028293937jhg
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <jsonInfos>

{"messages":[{"id":"30008","type":"OK","messageContent":"Some data..."}],"labelXmlReponse":"data","labelResponse":"data"}
--uuid:ea9ca368-2f73-4669-aa94-028293937jhg--
```

I need to retrieve only the json object. I can't do `json_decode()` on the response because of the text before and after the json. 
I tried with a regex to catch everything inside braces :

```
preg_match("/(\{(.*?)\})/", $res_curl, $output_array);
```

But this doesn't work because it ends on the first closing brace.

What should I do to catch the json from the response ?

**EDIT**

As asked in comment, here is my calling code, I'm using cURL :

```
$ch = curl_init($url.$action);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($requestParameter) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$res_curl = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: this API is broken (content-type is JSON, it should be valid JSON, period). You should notify the developers and not waste time working your way around it.

Comment: We need your calling code. That paste you put there contains the HTTP headers. You need just the body. Lets see your code. Don't hack it with regex!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using cURL? Just set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to false.

Comment: I've edited my question, you can check my calling code

Comment: Ok I see you set it to false, so there is the chance that the API devs have got it wrong?